# how to transfer Folder Between FTP And Remote Server?SSIS

Tags: ssis

I want to get a zip Folder from FTP And Put it for Process in Server with ip ...110.
on the Other Hand ,The Package is on server with ip . . .210
how should i do these transfer.
Now i just give Zip Folder ,And put it on my local Computer, and process files.

it is Mandatory that Program be on server 210

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `file system task` to transfer the files. Set up a network drive at your destination server(210) accessing the zip file on your source server(110). Then you can use this in the `file system task` as `source connection`.

In the end you can use this package before processing the zip file, either as a step of your processing job, or set up an own job.

Comment: is it possible to set username and password of server 110?