# how to FTP between two remote Servers on separate networks

Tags: ftp, lamp

I have read similar posts with no obvious solution.  We have three servers - 3 separate physical locations / 3 separate networks. we want to copy files from one server (source) to the other two servers and vise versa. We can Ftp to server successfully from local machines, but we are not able to FTP from server to server. We're on LAMP & use IP tables and assume there is something related to that blocking access from the server to make the connection(s), but my knowledge is very limited in that area. If anyone has any suggestions as to a general set of steps or troubleshoots to check, it would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You have not read similar posts here, because this is a site for programming questions and answers. FTP is not programming.

Comment: Pascal - I previously searched/read the links included below. I'm trying to use PHP to do the ftp part (my mistake for not tagging it as such) but something else is preventing it. My experience visiting StackOverflow has always been positive & think highly of the majority of the SO community... with the exception of someone blatantly calling me a Liar - sincere apologies for wasting your time.  [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126774/php-ftp-between-two-remote-servers

[link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024758/how-to-transfer-folder-between-ftp-and-remote-serverssis

Comment: ............................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can access the (3) servers from your local computer, it is probably an issue in your server trying to reach the outside world.
I would say you are missing an "OUTPUT" line in your iptable which allows output flow, something like:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Thank You. we implemented that based on your suggestion It's likely the first step and looking at other settings as well.